# iOS UIScrollView requireGestureToFail

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to call requireGestureToFail on the gesture that handles the scrolling in a UIView? I have a custom gesture, so that when it fires, I want the scrolling to be disabled.

I tried scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO. However, I cannot reenable it. I believe this is due to having multiple gestures on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think from IOS 5 you can do this . Suppose you have a swipe gesture in your scrollview,you can do this to avoid scrolling while swiping,

```
[swipeGesture requireGestureToFail:scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```